# VB.net Create contact from CSV file

Tags: vb.net

I've got this code which seems to loop through a list of contacts, however it doesn't create an outlook contact, nor does it generate an error. Any Ideas?

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser("c:\contacts.csv")
    Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data
    afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    afile.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}
    afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True


    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
    oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim oNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    oNs = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    oNs.Logon()

    Dim oItem As Outlook.ContactItem
    oItem = oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olContactItem)

    ' parse the actual file
    Do While Not afile.EndOfData
        Try
            CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields

            With oItem
                .FirstName = CurrentRecord(0)
                .LastName = CurrentRecord(1)
               End With

            oItem.Save()
        Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
            Stop
        End Try
    Loop
    MsgBox("Complete")
End Sub
```

Not sure if this is the best method, so I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the whole problem, but you should be creating each contact inside your loop (yeah, I prefer "Do Until" over "Do While Not"):

```
Do Until afile.EndOfData
    Try
        CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
        oItem = oApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olContactItem)
        With oItem
            .FirstName = CurrentRecord(0)
            .LastName = CurrentRecord(1)
            .Save()
        End With            
    Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
        Stop
    End Try
Loop
```